# Views Editing Section Missing

Tags: views

I upgraded a site from D6 to D7 and am coming across an interesting error with being able to edit my existing views. My views are all listed, but when I click on the edit button to edit a view the whole configuration section is missing- all the edit page shows is:

> Breadcrumb
>
> Title of view
>
> Auto preview
>   Preview with contextual filters:
>   Separate contextual filter values with a "/". For example, 40/12/10.
>   Update Preview

[image: screenshot of Views Edit Screen]

New views do have the configuration area. Any help or ideas on what I might use to search for a solution to someone else that might have had this issue would also be appreciated. I haven't been able to come up with the right search terms to help find the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the problem was that the views were content panes and I hadn't enabled content panes in the CTools module. As soon as I turned that on they worked fine again.